# How to get collection data from table sales_order_item in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to get data collection from table sales_order_item and join with other table.
How to do that?
I write this code.

```
$sale_order = $this->_resource->getTableName('sales_order');

        $sale_order_item_table = $this->_resource->getTableName('sales_order_item');

        $catalog_category_product_table = $this->_resource->getTableName('catalog_category_product');

        $catalog_category_entity_text_table = $this->_resource->getTableName('catalog_category_entity_text');
```

and I want to create collection but I don't know how to create right _salesOrderItemCollectionFactory
$saleOrderItemCollection = $this->_salesOrderItemCollectionFactory->create();

Please help me?

Thank you so much,
BienHV

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use getSelect to create join query like this then you load collection with this query.

```
public function execute()
{
    /* @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\Collection $collection*/
    $collection = $this->orderItemsCollectionFactory->create();
    $joinQuery = $collection->getSelect()
        ->join(['so' =>'sales_order'],'main_table.order_id = so.entity_id','state');
    $result = $collection->load($joinQuery);
    return $result->getData();
}
```